# C++ implementing CNN Error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line

Tags: c++, computer-vision, ubuntu-14.04, deep-learning

I'm testing a CNN implementation provided [here](https://github.com/btgraham/SparseConvNet/wiki/Installation). I run the command:

```
make cifar10 && ./cifar10
```

But I got the following messages:

```
g++ -o cifar10 BatchProducer.o ConvolutionalLayer.o ConvolutionalTriangularLayer.o IndexLearnerLayer.o MaxPoolingLayer.o MaxPoolingTriangularLayer.o NetworkArchitectures.o NetworkInNetworkLayer.o Picture.o Regions.o Rng.o SigmoidLayer.o SoftmaxClassifier.o SparseConvNet.o SparseConvNetCUDA.o SpatiallySparseBatch.o SpatiallySparseBatchInterface.o SpatiallySparseDataset.o SpatiallySparseLayer.o TerminalPoolingLayer.o cudaUtilities.o readImageToMat.o types.o utilities.o vectorCUDA.o vectorHash.o OpenCVPicture.o SpatiallySparseDatasetCIFAR10.o cifar10.o -lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lrt -larmadillo -lopenblas -lz --std=c++11 -O3
/usr/bin/ld: BatchProducer.o: undefined reference to symbol 'pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5'
//lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0: error adding symbols: DSO missing from command line
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [cifar10] Error 1
```

What's wrong with this? I installed all the dependencies listed in the webpage. I did not install CUDA because I tested the CPU version [here](https://github.com/btgraham/SparseConvNet-CPU). Therefore I don't think the error is due to missing CUDA. 
I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 and gcc 5.3.0.
Thank you all for helping me!!!

Answer (score 0):

Solution: add '-lz' to your makefile / GCC flags. In other words, your simply missing a library in your make steps, and check if you installled all dependencies

```
sudo apt-get install libarmadillo-dev libopencv-core-dev libopencv-highgui-dev sparsehash
```

Comment: Thank you. I followed your instructions and added the '-lz' to the GCC flags. But it seems nothing got changed. Did I do something wrong? I put all the messages printed out after I launch the compilation. Thank you very much!